# angular 8: Reactive Form match password

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have the reactive form in my angular project that defines like this:

```
this.createUserFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  'userName': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(256)]),
  'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)]),
  'roleNames': new FormArray([]),
  'password': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(32)]),
  'confirmPassword': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
});
```

how can I check the matching of password and confirmPassword?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a custom validator and use it in FormGroup like

```
    passwordConfirming(c: AbstractControl): { invalid: boolean } {
    if (c.get('password').value !== c.get('confirmPassword').value) {
        return {invalid: true};
    }
}
```

And you need to use this custom validator like.

```
 this.createUserFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  'userName': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(256)]),
  'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)]),
  'roleNames': new FormArray([]),
  'password': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(32)]),
  'confirmPassword': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
},{validator: this.passwordConfirming});
```

and check in html like

```
 <span *ngIf="createUserFormGroup.errors?.invalid">
      Password doesn't match
  </span>
```

Comment: At least in angular 10, validator should be "validators"

Answer (score 2):

For angular 7+ you can add a custom passwords match validator for your form :

```
private passwordsMatchValidator(form: FormGroup) {
    if (form.get('password') && form.get('confirmPassword')) {
        return form.get('password').value === form.get('confirmPassword').value ? null : { mismatch: true };
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then add it as a custom validator when creating your form :

```
this.createUserFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  'userName': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(256)]),
  'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)]),
  'roleNames': new FormArray([]),
  'password': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(32)]),
  'confirmPassword': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
}, this.passwordsMatchValidator);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have straightaway used `compare` validator of [`@rxweb/reactive-form-validators`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators) without creating a custom function and writing too much code in the component.

Install:

```
npm i @rxweb/reactive-form-validators
```

I have compared `confirmPassword` field and by mentioning the fieldName parameter with it. Here is the component code.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        password:['',], 
        confirmPassword:['', RxwebValidators.compare({fieldName:'password' })], 
    });
}
```

Here is the complete app.component.ts code where you can display the error message by declaring it globally like this.

```
ReactiveFormConfig.set({"validationMessage":{"compare":"Input does not match"}});
```

Here is the complete HTML code.

```
<div>
  <form  [formGroup]="userFormGroup">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="password" class="form-control"  />
     <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="userFormGroup.controls.password.errors">{{userFormGroup.controls.password.errors.compare.message}}<br/></small>    
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="confirmPassword" class="form-control"  />
    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="userFormGroup.controls.confirmPasswossrd.errors">{{userFormGroup.controls.confirmPassword.errors.compare.message}}<br/></small>
    </div>
    <button [disabled]="!userFormGroup.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7m48ih?file=src/app/compare-add.component.html)

Comment: Is it a Library...?

Comment: It's a npm package

Comment: Okay! but its always write your custom code *(if the code and feature is not complex)* instead of the library because in terms of Modification in the logic (which the library not provide) so you will have to revert the library changes. Please add the package URL in the answer

Comment: @PrashantPimpale In the case of comparing field, there is no modification of logic required. In such cases, its better to use library for simplicity of implementation.

Comment: Seen its downloads and features! Thanks

Comment: @SrishtiKhandelwal I agree with him, password validation is a two-liner. You don't need a full library to do that.

Comment: @Maryannah Its another benefit is the compare validator will not fire if the user enters a value in non comparison field, like as per dhaval answer this will fire non comparison field which is bit clumsy when the form is large. This is just my view, there may be better way than this.

Comment: Indeed, that's purely personal and library-based. But more importantly, that wasn't asked by the OP, so it's not really an argument to use it.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Hi Prashant I add this code in my template but get this error: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined

Comment: @karim have you referred to the stackblitz example i shared ?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale yes I add the same code in my project

Comment: @karim have you set the message in reactiveFormConfig in your app.component.ts

Comment: @PrashantPimpale yes I add it