# Passwords must match with reactive forms in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, validation

I tried some tutorials for password validations with reactive forms, but still can't finish my task. Including reading this post [angular 8: Reactive Form match password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801299/angular-8-reactive-form-match-password)  but not work for me.

This is my html & I think it's good:

```
<div class="input-group form-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input #password formControlName="confirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control"
              placeholder="Confirm *">
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"
            *ngIf="!!(this.registerFormGroup.controls.confirmPassword.errors.required && this.registerFormGroup.controls.confirmPassword.dirty)">Confirm Password is required
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"
            *ngIf="!!(this.registerFormGroup.controls.confirmPassword.errors.mustMatch && this.registerFormGroup.controls.confirmPassword.dirty)">Passwords must match
          </div>
```

This is my custom validator:

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export function MustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
        const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
        const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

        if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.mustMatch) {
            // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
            return;
        }

        // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
        if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
            matchingControl.setErrors({ mustMatch: true });
        } else {
            matchingControl.setErrors(null);
        }
    };
}
```

This is my RegisterFormGroup:

```
registerFormGroup(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    return formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      confirmPassword: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
        ]
      ],
    }, {
        validator: MustMatch('password', 'confirmPassword')
      });
  }
```

When type different password I receive the wanted error. But when type correct passwords, receive error in console:

```
RegisterComponent.html:56 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'required' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RegisterComponent.html:60)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23511)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23308)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
```

This is at line:60

```
*ngIf="!!(this.registerFormGroup.controls.confirmPassword.errors.required && this.registerFormGroup.controls.confirmPassword.dirty)">Confirm Password is required
```

I fix other errors, but can't resolve this. It's most likely small bug, which I can't see...

Comment: you missed a '?' it should be errors?

Comment: Use ? operator to avoid null  or undefined values as wel as *ngIf in template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use bellow code:

```
<div *ngIf="registerFormGroup.get('confirmPassword').invalid && registerFormGroup.get('confirmPassword').dirty" class="text-danger">
  <div *ngIf="registerFormGroup.get('confirmPassword').hasError('required')">
    *
  </div>
</div>
```